# Does this CSS technique have a name?

Tags: css

I've been using this technique for over a year, but I haven't seen it in use anywhere else. In brief, I'm formalizing display "states" or "modes" using CSS classes. I've tried searching for "css modes", "css states", "stateful css", etc. but if it exists then it doesn't use any of those names.

Here's a simple example of what I'm doing. The example is a responsive text input, the sort that would talk to the server and tell you dynamically whether the username you've chosen is already taken.

Markup:

```
<div id="username-container" class="username-mode-ready">
    <!-- input -->
    <label for="username" class="username-label">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" class="username-input" />

    <!-- icons -->
    <img src="error.png" class="icon error"/>
    <img src="ok.png" class="icon accepted"/>
    <img src="loading.gif" class="icon loading"/>

    <!-- messages -->
    <p class="message error">
        That username is not available.
    </p>
    <p class="message accepted">
        That username is available!
    </p>
    <p class="message loading">
        Loading ...
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Default = hidden */
#username-container .error,
#username-container .accepted,
#username-container .loading {
    display : none;
}

/* Show when appropriate */
#username-container.username-mode-error    .error,
#username-container.username-mode-accepted .accepted,
#username-container.username-mode-loading  .loading {
    display : block;
}
```

Now we would add our Javascript. When we go to the server we'll do:

```
$('username-container').className = 'username-mode-loading';
```

And when we return, we'll do one of the following based on the server response:

```
$('username-container').className = 'username-mode-accepted'; // Username available
$('username-container').className = 'username-mode-error';    // Username taken
```

This way, we can just change the className of the container to see different display modes without the need for manipulating element.style.display on a million different elements. We can also do more than show/hide:

CSS:

```
/* Set label color to green or red depending on availability */
#username-container.username-mode-accepted .username-label {
    color : green;
}
#username-container.username-mode-error .username-label {
    color : red;
}
```

Or apply styles across multiple modes:

Markup:

```
<img alt="Whew! I searched as hard as I could!" src="done-searching.png" class="icon done-searching"/>
```

CSS:

```
/* New icon should display in accepted and error modes */
#username-container .done-searching {
    display : none;
}
#username-container.username-mode-accepted .done-searching,
#username-container.username-mode-error    .done-searching {
    display : block;
```

Has this technique already been described? I'm about to start calling it mode-oriented CSS, for want of a name when I explain it to people, but I'd rather use the nice, real, Googlable name if there is one.

Comment: Since you're using a server and JavaScript, I wouldn't call it "CSS" anything. It's simply: responsive design

Comment: Have you ever looked at jQuery UI?

Comment: @Diodeus: How is this responsive?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think there's a name for this technique. It's such a natural part of CSS workflow (mine, at least) that I don't think I've really thought of this as a technique in its own right. But that could be just me.

Comment: I've used techniques like that before, never thought much of it and never heard any specific term used to describe it.

Comment: @Diodeus: Sorry, I should have been clearer what aspect of the example I was talking about. The communication with the server isn't the important part, but rather the use of display modes which encompass styles for multiple UI components. It may be responsive design, but it's the bunching together of CSS properties into easily debuggable states that I'm interested in.

Comment: Those are just good design practices. There is no special name.

Comment: @Diodeus I'm surprised this is so common. Do you know of any examples? They'd need three elements:

1) A container element
2) A finite set of mode classes applied to the container
3) Internal elements which respond to the mode classes

Thanks!

Comment: If there are no names for such a technique than why not simply make one? Something like "stateful css responsive" or something smarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these articles that kind of cover some of these ideas:

- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/prefixed-classes-bootstrap
- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/naming-convention-in-css
- http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/04/28/our-best-practices-are-killing-us/
- http://speakerdeck.com/u/andyhume/p/css-for-grown-ups-maturing-best-practises

Short answer: I don't know ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The first link led me to http://smacss.com/book/type-state which seems to describe something very similar to what I'm going for. A lot of that page is devoted to how "state rules" coexist with other SMACSS principles, which I'm not familiar with, so I need to learn more to know for sure if this is the term I'm looking for. Very helpful in any case - I'd been looking at OOCSS, which preaches against use of the descendant selector, which left me feeling insecure about using this technique. Glad to learn about SMACSS which embraces it.

Comment: Further reading: http://smacss.com/book/state Still learning about SMACSS but this looks like exactly what I'm thinking of.